# ORDER BY NOT EXIST in two column from another table. Is it possible?

Tags: mysql

I have a query ended with `ORDER BY NOT EXISTS`.
I am having an issue with `NOT EXISTS` to look at two columns from another table. The query works with `col1`, but not with `col2`

```
FROM
    t1
    JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
    ...
ORDER BY NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT col1, col2
        FROM t1
    WHERE t1.id2 = t2.id2
        AND MONTH(t1.date) = MONTH(CURDATE())
    ) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Just testing it and found out the solution, that if i use

```
WHERE t1.id = t2.id
```

and instead of

```
WHERE t1.id2 = t2.id2
```

it worked. I told them to look at the current table id `PK` column and not the another table id `FK` and it worked.